# Acer Laptop with two disks: second ntfs harddisk become "ESP" Fat32 disk, data gone

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ntfs, fat32

I have an Acer A715-71G-706B, two disk ssd+hdd. Recently I needed to connect diffrent hdd in place of laptop's  to check it's data. After returning to orginial 1TB hdd I've noticed that my disk instead of my data is gone, there is 998MB D: drive instead of 1TB ntfs drive D:.

Why did it happend, and how can I recover my disk/partition?
The only thing I did was removing 1TB drive, insert another disk to check data, install original 1TB hdd into laptop. Problems.

Comment: Before trying anything else, *make an image of the disk* to prevent destruction of data. Do this *without booting from the damaged HDD*.

Comment: Laptop is booting od m.2 disk. Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partition table was apparently destroyed.
You may try some partition-recovery program to try and recover
your partitions, such as :

- [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html)
- [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

If the partitions are beyond recovery, all you can do is try to recover your data.
See this article for a list of such products with reviews:
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).
Recover the data to some other disk - never write to a damaged disk.

Comment: For now I haven't done anything with this partition. I was running testdisk but it for now it couldn't find anything. I need to run full scan. Any ideas why this happend?

Comment: Did you replace the disk while Windows was still running or was it turned off?

Comment: I know that "there are not stupid questions" but... :D no.

Comment: It somehow seems that the partition table was fully or partly replaced. Windows by default never really turns off because of fast boot, so if the disk was replaced while it was not fully shutdown, then it might make the mistake of writing to it some or all of the previous partition table or messing it up in some such way.

Comment: I wasn't doing any partiton operations  when it did happen.

Comment: You said you replaced the disk, that means that Windows turned off with one disk and woke up with another. Your problem isn't unique and I've encountered it here once before, although it's very extremely rare, to your bad luck.

Comment: That's a curiosity - that could be it. Any way I needed to run file recovery software to retrieve my files back. Thanks.